# allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' - MVC3 ERROR

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-hosting

I'm developing an application in MVC3 (http://www.colombiatrolley.com/sitrolley). In my computer it runs correctly, but when I upload it to the server (a hosting service) I get this error:

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

I know it is a very common error but I have not fixed it yet.

[image: Error capture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some config sections are only allowed at the "root" of the application, then `authentication` section is one of them.

You need to configure IIS to run your your site as an application, not a sub-directory in an existing application.

For IIS 7+, right click the directory that contains your web application, and select "Convert to Application".

**EDIT**:

Arie van Someren is right. Looking carefully at your error, you want the `<authentication>` configuration to be in the web.config one level up, not the web.config in Views.

Comment: It only appears that option (Convert to Application) for the subdirectories, like "Views". I´ve already clicked on it but the error remains. Do you have another possible answer?

Comment: Do you have the <authentication> tag in the web.config inside your Views subfolder? This might explain the exception.

Comment: @migueljimenezz @`ArievanSomeren is right, you want your authentication element to be on the web.config one level up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by deleting the obj folder that appeared after doing a "Build > Publish".